# Cannot see anything from #prefix and #suffix fields

Tags: drupal, drupal-6

I placed some table tags in #prefix and #suffix fields of the $forms array, but i cannot see anything in rendered page, why?

Answer (score 0):

If you provide a copy of the form code, that would make debugging a lot easier.

One reason, could be the form items you added `#suffix` and `#prefix` to don't support it. You can check the [Form API](http://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/developer--topics--forms_api_reference.html/6).
Another possibility is that you simply made a mistake when you made them, or are using a theming function that doesn't render them.

But this is merely guesses...

Comment: well, i placed this code into template.php:
http://pastebin.com/2dPrzNHw

with var_dump i get this array:
http://pastebin.com/Wiu6JUdp

Comment: What are you trying to do? Whatever it is you want to do, this is definitely the wrong way to do it.

Comment: :-)) i want to do this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312668/modificate-content-profile-form-to-show-checkboxes-in-the-matrix

Comment: I posted a answer at your other question since it belongs there: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2312668/modificate-content-profile-form-to-show-checkboxes-in-the-matrix/2319543#2319543